# How to "Share Image With Account Number" via API or CLI?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

What is the correct pattern to programmatically "Share Image With Account Number"? I don't see anything in the Softlayer CLI or the API for doing so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see:

```
"""
Share image template.

The script shares an image template to another account, it makes
a single call to SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group::permitSharingAccess
method.
For more information please see below.

Important manual pages
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/permitSharingAccess
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
API_USERNAME = 'set me'

# Generate one at https://control.softlayer.com/account/users
API_KEY = 'set me'

"""
The image template which you wish to share
To get the list of images templates in your account 
call the Softlayer_Account::getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups method
"""
imageTemplateId = 1796623

# the account you wish to share the image template
accountToShare = 207819

# Declare the API client
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=API_USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
blockDeviceTemplateGroupService = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group']

try:
    # Calling the permitSharingAccess method to share the image template
    result = blockDeviceTemplateGroupService.permitSharingAccess(accountToShare, id=imageTemplateId)
    pp(result)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    """
    # If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with the
    # error message.
    """
    print("Unable to share the image template. \nfaultCode= %s, \nfaultString= %s"
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Comment: Great! out of curiosity can this be done from the CLI?

Comment: nope the SLCLI does not have that feature implemented